# Database design for questionbased voting system, has the normalization gone wrong?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema, voting

I need to create a database system wherein *normal users* can create *questions with, only 2, belonging answers* and these *questions* can then get a up- or down-vote by people visiting the site.

I am wondering in which way it would be best to create this database, specifically the tables required and their relations.

Within this site, there will be, at least, **two user groups**. *Normal users* and *institution users*. *Institution users* should be able to create a profile for their *institution*, *normal users* should then be able to choose an (already created) *institution* to belong to.

Each *institution* will per time basis have one *question (with answers)* assigned to them depending on which *question* on the site that has the most up-votes from *normal users* belonging to that *institution*.

The *answers* will, per question, be voted on. This will happen outside the database via *sensors* and the *sensor* will send numerical information representing number of votes each *answer* receives.

I am fairly new to creating databases and this is the first one I am creating alone. I have, below, tried to set up the tables that I think are **relevant in this database system and their relations**.

[image: Database system for voting, users and question.]

Tables:
**User**: *UserID*, UserName, UserEmail, Password
**Question_Votes**: *QuestionID*, *UserID*, UpVotes, DownVotes
**Question**: *QuestionID*, QuestionText
**Institution_Users**: *UserID*, *InstitutionID*
**Institution**: *InstitutionID*, InstitutionName, InstitutionEmail, InstitutionPassword, InstitutionAddress, InstitutionInfo
**Institution_Questions**: *InstitutionID*, *QuestionID*, IsActive
**Institution_Question_Answers**: *InstitutionID*, *QuestionID*, *SensorAnswerID*
**Sensor_Answers**: *SensorAnswerID*, *SensorID*, *Answer1ID*, *Answer2ID*
**Sensor**: *SensorID*, SensorLocation, SensorNumber, SensorAnswer1, SensorAnswer2
**Answer1**: *Answer1ID*, AnswerText
**Answer2**: *Answer2ID*, AnswerText

I have tried to normalize the database as much as possible, but being new to this, I might have failed miserably or made it more complicated than it should be. I might have made many mistakes, please do point them out, it's the only way I'll learn!