# Putting data in a normalized database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I am building a database system wherein users can vote on questions that they themselves can create. What I am struggling with is populating the database correctly, especially because I have tried normalizing it and it confuses me greatly! I am extremely new to SQL and MySQLi.

In the below database, how would I best put in user information when a person makes a profile on my webpage and then use that information again when I, for example, want to tie their UserID to the QuestionID and the Up- or down-votes they made?

[image: Database system for voting, users and question.]

I'm looking for assistance on the design of the database, but especially help with my question about putting data into the database and 'tying' it together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try out something simpler and normalize it one step at a time.

**Users table is good**

```
create table users (
  userid int not null auto_increment primary key,
  email varchar(100) not null,
  password varchar(255) not null
);
```

**Questions table**

I'd just mark who asked the question right in the questions table to begin with

```
create table questions (
  questionid int not null auto_increment primary key,
  question mediumtext or whatever,
  userid int not null,
  add fk here for userid
);
```

**Question votes - many to many/junction table**

```
create table question_votes (
  question_votesid int not null auto_increment primary key,
  questionid int not null,
  voterid int not null,
  votedate timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
  score int not null,
  add fk here for questionid and voterid
);
```

**Answers table**

```
create table answers (
  answerid int not null auto_increment primary key,
  answer mediumtext or whatever,
  questionid int not null,
  userid int not null,
  add fk here for questionid, userid
);
```

You have the option of creating answers that only holds answers and a junction table called question_answers that holds questionid, answerid columns. You can also choose to put question_userid and answer_userid in this table. Read the last paragraph to get to an answer by yourself.

**Answer votes table**

```
create table answer_votes (
  answer_votesid int not null auto_increment primary key,
  answerid int not null,
  voterid int not null,
  votedate timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
  score int not null,
  add fk here for answerid and voterid
);
```

Put some dummy data into it and start asking yourself questions - what kind of information do I need out of this. What if X happens; can this schema adapt to the answers I will be asked in the future when X happens? etc.

As you go through those Q&A in your head, you will find out where you should normalize and to what degree.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering Zedfoxus. This database has given me a lot of headaches cause it needs to do so much and I'm very new to it. I made a whole post trying to explain what I wanted to do with it, I was wondering if I could have you take a look at that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111419/database-design-for-questionbased-voting-system-normalization-gone-wrong
If not, then thank you for your answer, I will try making a few simple tables at a time and see if I can make it easier for myself!

Comment: Hi @user2304993, my answer to your other question will be similar to this. Normalize two tables first. Run some queries and think of scenarios for which you would have to answer questions. Then add the next table and repeat the exercise. Add another table and repeat the exercise and so on

Comment: Oh, also, if you find this answer useful, can you put a closure to your question by accepting it? Thank you.